# Oracle Apex 5 Rows for page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Hy guys i have just start to develop with Apex 5 i have this problem.
In this page, i have 15 rows, and the other page i have 1 row, but if i press next page, i have this problem.
[image]

and i can't go in another page, and if i press ok or cancel the action is the same, the page doesn't refresh.
i print the setting for this page.

[image]

Sorry guys but i'm at the begging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like you should first save changes you've made on this page - otherwise, if you proceed to the next page, those changes will be lost.

If you want to "skip" that warning, navigate to Page properties, scroll down to "Navigation" and turn off "**Warn on unsaved changes**".